# How to stop vim pane from blinking in tmux?

Tags: linux, vim, tmux

I'm using vim inside tmux and it does a very annoying thing: whenever I do some edits in vim (no matter if I save or not) and then immediately switch to another pane, the vim pane's indicator starts blinking until I return to it. This is a common scenario when debugging, when I'm jumping constantly between code and make/gdb output. This doesn't always happen, it only happens when my I/O speeds are low (I'm logged in to a remote server that has a NFS file system and the networked disk tends to get very slow at times), so I think what's happening is that vim does some I/O (e.g writing to swap files) and wants to let me know it's done. It won't happen if I don't immediately switch to another pane and give it some time to do its housekeeping (but that's obviously counterproductive).

Here's a gif of what happens immediately after I switch from pane 1  which has vim:

[image]

Here's my tmux config:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color" # colors!
setw -g xterm-keys on
set -s escape-time 0                      # fastest command sequences
set -sg repeat-time 600                   # increase repeat timeout
#set -s quiet on                           # disable various messages
#set -s focus-events on

set -g prefix2 C-q                        # GNU-Screen compatible prefix
bind C-a send-prefix -2

set -q -g status-utf8 on                  # expect UTF-8 (tmux < 2.2)
setw -q -g utf8 on

set -g history-limit 5000                 # boost history

set-window-option -g mode-keys vi

# edit configuration
bind e new-window -n '~/.tmux.conf.local' "sh -c '\${EDITOR:-vim} ~/.tmux.conf.local && tmux source ~/.tmux.conf && tmux display \"~/.tmux.conf sourced\"'"

set-option -g repeat-time 0

# reload configuration
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display '~/.tmux.conf sourced'

# -- display -------------------------------------------------------------------

set -g base-index 1         # start windows numbering at 1
setw -g pane-base-index 1   # make pane numbering consistent with windows

setw -g automatic-rename on # rename window to reflect current program
set -g renumber-windows on  # renumber windows when a window is closed

set -g set-titles on                        # set terminal title
set -g set-titles-string '#h ❐ #S ● #I #W'

set -g display-panes-time 800 # slightly longer pane indicators display time
set -g display-time 1000      # slightly longer status messages display time

set -g status-interval 10     # redraw status line every 10 seconds

# clear both screen and history
bind -n C-l send-keys C-l \; run 'sleep 0.05 && tmux clear-history'

# activity
set -g monitor-activity on
set -g visual-activity off
```

Here's my vim config:

```
set encoding=utf-8  " The encoding displayed.
set fileencoding=utf-8  " The encoding written to file.

set nocompatible
filetype off
syntax on

set tabstop=4
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4

set number

set hlsearch
set list
set listchars=tab:>-
set listchars+=eol:�
set listchars+=space:�

set splitright
set splitbelow

colorscheme molokai

" Vundle config
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on

set laststatus=2
set updatetime=1000

au BufNewFile,BufRead * if &syntax == '' | set syntax=sh | endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blinking kept bugging me so I searched more and finally found an answer courtesy of [this link](http://www.simoniong.info/vim/tmux/work-flow/2012/01/28/how-to-stop-annoying-bell.html). Turns out one has to disable the bell in tmux.

I've reproduced the answer below for the sake of reference:

```
# disable in vim

set vb t_vb=     " no visual bell & flash

# disable bell in tmux
# disable sound bell
set -g bell-action none
# disable visual bell
set -g visual-bell off
```